# Where are the directions for how to play Angry Birds located?

Tags: angry-birds

I'm trying to figure out how to play Angry Birds, but I can't find any directions for how to play anywhere. Where are the directions located?

Comment: Directions?  Huh?  What directions?  How to play the game?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there are in-game directions, although every now and then it will display a tip or show you how to do something.

This link provides good information on how to play Angry Birds:
[Link to How to Play Angry Birds](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Angry-Birds)

However, I'll summarize it for you.

1. Download the game
2. Understand what you're trying to do (destroy all of the pigs)
3. Pull back the slingshot with your fingers. This will show you the flight path of the bird. When ready to launch it, release your finger.

There are many different birds, each with various abilities! Figure out what they do to increase your effectiveness!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There is a sort-of helpful tip menu in the game that shows you what each bird does if you tap the screen after releasing the bird. If you're talking about in general instructions, you need to destroy all the pigs in each level using the allotted number of birds. Use the slingshot and the dotted path to aim for the pigs while trying to get a high score by damaging/destroying other blocks.

Scoring summary 
Blocks damage - 10-500 points until destroyed 
Each pig "killed" - 5000 points 
Each leftover bird - 10000 points